# Add numbers of unknown types

Tags: java, parsing, number-formatting

I'm trying to parse and add 2 numbers together where I don't know which type they are (int, float, etc.), and I'm trying to store the result in the most appropriate type. For instance, if I get 2 ints, I want the result to be an int, but if I get an int and a double, I want the result to be a double. How would I go about doing this?

One idea that I had was to try parsing as an int first, then long, then float, ... to see which type it was. Is there a better way to do this rather than trying/catching the NumberFormatExceptions?

Ex:

```
String number1 = "5";
String number2 = "3.4";

Object answer = add(number1, number2);
```

What would add() look like?

Comment: *Why* do you want the type to be different based on the input?

Comment: I guess type what I really want is the value to be correct and space isn't an issue, so everything with doubles should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would read the all as a `double`, or a `BigDecimal`.  This will be simpler and possibly more efficient than trying to find the "optimal" type.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the numbers are valid (for example no special symbols in them), then I would search the input for dots (`.`). If I find a dot, I would parse it as `double`; if not, as `int`.